# How to launch browser only once using selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to launch firefox and chrome only once for the same test. When I use the following command, firefox launches once, but chrome launches 3 times. Help Please. Thanks!

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5666  -browser browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1 -browser browserName=chrome, maxInstance=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `maxSession` to limit the amount of sessions to be available at one time.

```
java -jar ... -maxSession <int>
```